# My Desktop folder is missing from favorites menu and also from Finder Preferences.

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-pro

My Desktop folder is missing from favorites menu and also from Finder Preferences. How do I restore to the favorites menu?

Comment: If the Finder is the active Windows, the "Go To" menu should be visible. In this menu you should find the "Desktop". As stated in this menu or on the mac page, you can also press "Shift-Command-D": https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236#finder

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming by your Favorites menu you mean in the Finder's Sidebar?

To rectify this:

- Go to Finder
- Select Finder > Preferences
- Click on the Sidebar tab
- Make sure the Desktop checkbox is ticked
- Exit Preferences

If you mean that the option for your desktop isn't actually available in the above Preferences, try the following as a test:

- Open a window in Finder
- In the Sidebar, click on your username
- In the list of folders, you should see the Desktop folder
- Now drag the Desktop folder to your Favorites in the Sidebar

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To clarify, yes my Desktop is missing from the preference menu. I'm sorry, but my user name is not in the sidebar. More help please!

Comment: I can add my desktop to favorites fine. however over and over again i find that it has disappeared at some future point. it's been happening to me for the last year or so and i haven't been able to determine the length or behavior that makes it go away.

Answer (score 6):

You probably have selected the option to have your Desktop and Documents folders appearing on iCloud. This is an "either or" option, i.e., if you selected that in the iCloud section of your computer preferences, your local desktop won't be visible in your Finder sidebar or even in your Finder sidebar preferences. To get your Desktop back, turn off "Desktop and Documents" in iCloud preferences...

Comment: Specifically, go to System Preferences > Internet Accounts (or search "iCloud") > iCloud Drive > Options and uncheck Desktop & Documents Folders.

Comment: Wow! Now that's a dumb way of developing "Apple"! I just had this problem... wish it was mentioned in preferences that they would "disappear" using the feature! And unfortunately, unchecking "Desktop and Documents" did not restore my folders... The documents folder was visible in the sidebar, but nothing was in it. And there was still nothing on my desktop, nor a folder in the sidebar... nor visible under my username! I had move the folder, and then the items from the icloud folder, and then delete them from the icloud server to restore it all. NEVER AGAIN will I try that ridiculous feature!!!